# Simple Box Project doesn't work as aspected

Tags: 8thwall-web

I actually trying to show a red cube on a post card (image tracker).
Unfortunately I can't see the cube. So I try to position a red cube in the room.
But I don't see him either. What am I doing wrong?
Since I am a complete beginner, this is probably a very simple problem.

Here is the content of the body.html

```
<a-scene
  xrextras-gesture-detector
  xrextras-almost-there
  xrextras-loading
  xrextras-runtime-error
  xrweb>
  <a-camera></a-camera>
  <a-entity position="0 0 20" geometry="primitive: box; width: 1; height: 1; depth: 1;" material="color: red"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Thanks for your answers.

André

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest cloning our [blank sample project](https://www.8thwall.com/8thwall/unitcube-aframe) which places a cube in world space.

In the provided code snippet, the `z` position of the cube is set to 20, which is quite far behind the camera.